# Limit the number of documents in a mongodb collection , without FIFO policy

Tags: mongodb

I'm building an application to handle ticket sales and expect to have really high demand.  I want to try using MongoDB with multiple concurrent client nodes serving a node.js website (and gracefully handle failure of clients).

I've read "[Limit the number of documents in a collection in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10995868/limit-the-number-of-documents-in-a-collection-in-mongodb)" (which is completely unrelated) and "[Is there a way to limit the number of records in certain collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475905/is-there-a-way-to-limit-the-number-of-records-in-certain-collection)" (but that talks about capped collections, where the new documents overwrite the oldest documents).

Is it possible to limit the number of documents in a collection to some maximum size, and have documents after that limit just be rejected.  The simple example is adding ticket sales to the database, then failing if all the tickets are already sold out.

I considered having a `NumberRemaining` document, which I could atomically decerement until it reaches `0` but that leaves me with a problem if a node crashes between decrementing that number, and saving the purchase of the ticket.

Comment: Could the # of tickets (stored as a `ticket id`), ever exceed the max size of a single MongoDB document (16MB)? You can only atomically set one document at a time (so maybe just store the successful ticket transactions in a single document). MongoDB isn't often a good fit for a multiple-document transactional system like you're describing, but 10gen has a pattern that could work: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/

Comment: That's a good suggestion actually, a single document could support about 2 million ticket sales based on that.  Only issue is how "hot" that one record would be, it would become a slight perf bottleneck but that's probably a good plan.  I can then store the documents separately (and add them before attempting to add them to the list of successful tickets).

Comment: If you add it as an answer I'll mark it as accepted

Comment: If you want atomicity of ticket sales here then the bottleneck will exist either on table/collection level or document level, it is prolly easier on document level since that document will be in memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the tickets in a single MongoDB document. As you can only atomically set one document at a time, you shouldn't have a problem with document dependencies that could have been solved by using a traditional transactional database system.

As a document can be up to 16MB, by storing only a `ticket_id` in a master document, you should be able to store plenty of tickets without needing to do any extra complex document management. While it could introduce a hot spot, the document likely won't be very large. If it does get large, you could use more than one document (by splitting them into multiple documents as one document "fills", activate another).

If that doesn't work, 10gen has a [pattern](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/) that might fit.

Comment: 2 phase commits are not atomic as such there is still a small possibility that there could be more tickets sold than available.

Comment: The two phase commit option is pseudo atomic, in that it is always possible to return to a consistent state with a regular cleanup job.

Comment: @ForbesLindesay Ensuring that the job is consistent in itself, there is nothing past the application level to ensure that, no level isolation etc on the database end to know this, effectively to not over sell a ticketed performance you would have to come back after closing of the sales and double check who has tickets and who does not

Comment: Once the two phase commit has terminated, it would be done, it's just that sometimes a transaction would start, then have to be rolled back.

Answer (score 1):

My only solution so far (I'm hoping someone can improve on this):

Insert documents into an un-capped collection as they arrive.  Keep the implicit `_id` value of `ObjectID`, which can be sorted and will therefore order the documents by when they were added.

Run all queries ordered by `_id` and limited to the max number of documents.

To determine whether an insert was "successful", run an additional query that checks that the newly inserted document is within the maximum number of documents.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was: I use an extra count variable in another collection. This collection has a validation rule that avoids count variables to become negative. Count variable should always be non negative integer number.

"count": { "$gte": 0 }

The algorithm was simple. Decrement the count by one. If it succeed insert the document. If it fails it means there is no space left.

Vice versa for deletion.

Also you can use transactions to prevent failures(Count is decremented but service is failed just before insertion operation).